# Vowpal Wabbit batch predict + spark support

Tags: python, apache-spark, vowpalwabbit

Im trying to use VowpalWabbit to predict on millions of examples using the python API.

For one example

```
features="| feat1:23 feat2:-0.3 feat3:4245"
model.predict(features)
```

and it works fine.
I saw that there is [predict_multi](https://vowpalwabbit.org/docs/vowpal_wabbit/python/latest/reference/vowpalwabbit.pyvw.pylibvw.html#vowpalwabbit.pyvw.pylibvw.vw.predict_multi) but somehow when I use a list of features I get

```
features_list = features * 2
model.predict(features_list)
    TypeError: No registered converter was able to produce a C++ rvalue of type boost::shared_ptr<VW::example> from this Python object of type str
```

Assuming I have 1 million records I dont want to forloop over each of them while using `model.predict()`
I would like to use batch predict on them.
I already know the list of features can be saved in a file and I can use commandline to predict over the entire file. But doing this adds latency I want to use Python Vowpalwabbit API

Answer (score 1):

VW is primarily targeted at as an online learning system. Therefore, predict is a single prediction and does not currently support batching. The best thing to do in this case is to loop over the examples and call predict.

This is actually why I renamed `predict` to `predict_one` in the new Python bindings. You can [check them out](https://vowpal-wabbit-next.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#vowpal_wabbit_next.Workspace.predict_one) if you are interested.

Comment: I see that based on the [repository description](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/py-vowpal-wabbit-next) this is an experimental library, is there any plan to incorporate a batch API in the near future?
I'm already using the `predict`  from `vowpal-wabbit` library as `predict_one`

Comment: We've talked generally about a batch API, but I don't think it is something that will be added in the near future. This is mainly because internally there is little optimization that can be done as a result, given the online nature of the algorithms. Are there any specific benefits you are after that don't apply when manually learning your batch in a loop?

Comment: More than batch learning my use case requires batch predict. This will cater to realtime predict use cases as well as batch predict use cases but with least amount of latency